# How to console inside the detailCellRendererParams of ag grid masterdetail in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Select(BandWidthState.get('collection')) bandWidth$: Observable<Array<any>>;
    @Select(BandWidthState.get('loading')) loading$: Observable<boolean>;
    @Select(BandWidthState.get('totalRecords')) totalRecords$: Observable<number>;
    gridApi: any;
    gridOptions = new AgGridOptions();

    rowData = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    columnDefs = GridOptions.default.columnDefs;
    columnDef: any;

    detailCellRendererParams = {
        detailGridOptions: {
            columnDefs: [
                { headerName: 'ping', field: 'ping', suppressMenu: true, width: 130, minWidth: 130 },
                { headerName: 'download', field: 'dl', suppressMenu: true },
                { headerName: 'upload', field: 'ul', suppressMenu: true },
                { headerName: 'ispcon', field: 'ispcon', suppressMenu: true, width: 90, minWidth: 90, maxWidth: 90 },
                { headerName: 'date start', field: 'dateStart', suppressMenu: true, sort: 'desc' },
                { headerName: 'date end', field: 'dateEnd', suppressMenu: true, sort: 'desc' }
            ],
            onFirstDataRendered: function (params: any) {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        },
        getDetailRowData: function (params: any) {
            console.log(params);
        }
    };
    constructor(
        private store: Store
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBandWidth();
    }

    async getBandWidth() {
        await this.store.dispatch(new BandWidthList({ start: 1, length: this.pageSize })).toPromise();
    }
    isRowMaster = function (dataItem: any) {
        return dataItem ? dataItem.data.length > 0 : false;
    };
```

here's the html code:

```
<ag-grid-angular
        #gridTable style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-balham"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [masterDetail]="true"
        [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
        [rowData]="rowData | async"
        [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
        [isRowMaster]="isRowMaster"
        [animateRows]="true"
        [suppressContextMenu]="true"
        [pagination]="true"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

what I'm trying to do here is to console the `params` in `getDetailRowData` and `isRowData`, but it doesn't show in the dev tool console.

When I'm trying to console the `params` of `getDetailRowData` and isRowData, it doesn't show the data. I want to check it if there's a data or don't have data.

Comment: Where are you invoking the function? .. BTW just to be clear, the functions are in the objects?, it is kind of weird, as a recommendation, you probably should define a class.

Comment: I will update my code

Comment: done update my code

Comment: I still can't find where, in your code, is the function `getDetailRowData` invoked, and where is `isRowData`?

Comment: i added my html

Comment: OK, now I understand why you have functions in the object, and why you didn't invoke the functions, both are invoked by the component AgGridAngular. Nevermind my comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the Master / Detail module. The example from ag includes all the modules. Seen here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

Import: 
`import { AllModules } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";`

Component:
`public modules: Module[] = AllModules;`

HTML

```
<ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [modules]="modules"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [masterDetail]="true"
      [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```